# Python gevent pool.join() waiting forever

Tags: python, multithreading, gevent, greenlets

I have a function like this

```
def check_urls(res):
    pool = Pool(10)
    print pool.free_count()
    for row in res:
        pool.spawn(fetch, row[0], row[1])
    pool.join()
```

`pool.free_count()` outputs value 10.

I used `pdb` to trace. Program works fine until `pool.spawn()` loop.

But its waiting forever at `pool.join()` line.

Can someone tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But its waiting forever at pool.join() line.*
>   *Can someone tell me whats wrong?*

Nothing!

Though, I first wrote what's below the line, the `join()` function in gevent is still behaving pretty much the same way as in subprocess/threading. It's blocking until all the greenlets are done.

If you want to only test whether all the greenlets in the pool are over or not, you might want to check for the [`ready()`](https://github.com/surfly/gevent/blob/master/gevent/greenlet.py#L117) on each greenlet of the pool:

```
is_over = all(gl.ready() for gl in pool.greenlets)
```

Basically, `.join()` is not waiting forever, it's waiting until your threads are over. If one of your threads is never ending, then `join()` will block forever. So make sure every greenlet thread terminate, and `join()` will get back to execution once all the jobs are done.

---

edit: The following applies only to subprocess or threading modules standard API. The GEvent's greenlet pools is not matching the "standard" API.

The [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) method on a Thread/Process has for purpose to make the main process/thread wait forever until the children processes/threads are over.

You can use the `timeout` parameter to make it get back to execution after some time, or you can use the `is_alive()` method to check if it's running or not without blocking.

In the context of a process/thread pool, the [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.join) also needs to be triggered ***after*** a call to either `close()` or `terminate()`, so you may want to:

```
for row in res:
    pool.spawn(fetch, row[0], row[1])
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: I'm not seeing `is_alive` method here. https://github.com/surfly/gevent/blob/master/gevent/pool.py

Comment: oh, I missed your `gevent` tag /o\ my bad, I'm talking about standard process or thread pools.

Comment: anyway, the `is_alive` method equivalent would be on each greenlet process, not on the pool itself.

Comment: Also I'm getting this error `AttributeError: 'Pool' object has no attribute 'close'`

Comment: I still don't get your answer. Do I have to use `is_over` instead of `pool.join()`?

Comment: it all depends on the context of your code, that I do not have. If you call `pool.join()` it **WILL** block per design until all your threads are over and execution is ready to get back into your main loop. If you want to have it not blocking, but only checking regularly whether your threads are over, you can use the `is_over` snippet I gave you.